# java.lang.IllegalStateException: "Failed to get external storage files directory" Emulator

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

I seem to have an issue. For some reason, my emulator just started throwing this error, seemingly out of the blue.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get external storage files directory
```

I haven't changed anything (that I know of) that would have affected this and it works find while testing on a real device.

Code at error

```
public void download(){
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(groups));
    request.setTitle("groups.txt");
    request.setDescription("File is being downloaded.....");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), null, "groups.txt");
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);


    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you are passing in `getApplicationContext()` instead of just passing in the Context of your Activity? That might be causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your [setDestinationInExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalFilesDir%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function, you have set directory path = null. So it is not able to find in which directory groups.txt has to be stored. Also I don't understand why you need to send application context instead of context of the activity.

Comment: what should I put if I want it to be stored in the base folder? Also, why does it work on real devices?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html   Check out the various options available here and choose